# How do I code to store the data permanently in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have read the documentation but still unable to figure out where to insert the command so that my topic stores the logs forever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are properties like `log.retention.hours`, `log.retention.bytes` which controls for much time these logs will be retained. You can set both of these properties to `-1` to retain your logs forever.

Comment: And in which file should I set them?

Comment: `server.properties`

Comment: Compacted topics also keep the most recent keyed message forever

Answer (score 2):

As @pulkit-singhal said, you can configure the *retention* period as a server default in the `server.properties` - for full details see the [reference doc](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs). You can also set it per-topic using [`kafka-topics.sh`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#topicconfigs).

You also should be aware of the concept of [*Log Compaction*](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction), which is another way of enabling infinite retention and is commonly used. This gives you a way to retain for every given **key**, the *latest* **value**. Log compaction is enabled by setting `log.cleanup.policy=compact`

Which you use (`-1` as the time & size retention policy, or log compaction) depends on your use case.

Comment: If i set log.cleanup.policy=compact, no duplication? thanks :)

Comment: You will have duplicated messages by key anyway, because only compacts messages older than 7 days, the last 7 days will not be compacted. Basically with the compaction will retain the last message by keys older than the `retention.ms`, and you will also have all messages in the last `retention.ms`.

Comment: @padilo - are you sure it's the `retention.ms` and not `min.compaction.lag.ms`? I've yet to find a reference that says the standard retention time is how long a key will persist until compaction

Comment: You are right. It's `min.compaction.lag.ms` not `retention.ms`, `retention.ms` is only for deletion policy